# Android Studio - avoid layout warning for different APIs

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I have this in res/layout

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt"
    android:text="@string/..."
    android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

I get warnings that layout_toRightOf should be layout_toEndOf and that layout_marginLeft should be layout_marginStart to better support right to left layouts.

So I made 2 layouts and put the other one inside layout-v17 and changed what it wanted. While layout-v17 is OK now, the warnings on the original layout file are still there, how can I let it know I already handled that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These warning come from Lint, a tool implemented in your SDK, which is checking the whole project looking for potential bugs.
Check [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html) and [this](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint/suppressing-lint-warnings) out.

Here's a [list](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint-checks) of Lint checks, each of which can be ignored using the `tools:ignore=` attribuite, as long as you have defined `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` in your root view. 
Of course this feature should be used only when needed, as lint checks can be useful in preventing bugs.

The attribute related to your issue, which in any case shouldn't be really annoying, is `RtlHardcoded`.

```
<RelativeLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="RtlHardcoded" >

    <TextView
        android:text="@string/text"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Note that you can also disable specific `Lint` checks from your IDE options for the whole project, but I wouldn't do that. (in Android Studio, Project Settings -> Inspections).

**Edit:**
Note also that this is not ignoring a real issue. I suggested you to do so because I imagined you just being "bothered" by a warning about a situation you already managed. In these cases, `tools:ignore` can be used to tell Lint "OK, I'm aware of the issue and I already managed it" (most of the cases, Lint is smart enough to notice on its own).

Regarding right-to-left layouts, best way to deal with them is to put both left(right) / start(end) attributes. On API>17, the latter will have priority.

Comment: I don't like ignoring issues as a solution for problems unless I have to, I was hoping there is a cleaner way.

Comment: That's not ignoring issues. You are just saying Lint not to be worried about right-to-left devices in that layout, and that's absolutely legit, because newer devices will load your alternative layout.

Comment: Apart from that, right way to manage this situation is to put both left-start / right-end attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Put twice
layout_toRightOf
and layout_toEndOf in the same textview

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/txt"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/txt"
    />
```

Comment: The problem is that for this attribute or the other one, it says that some devices will crash if I put both instead of just ignoring the newer one. This is why I made 2 different layout files

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<TextView
android:id="+id/textView1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignBaseline="id/txt" 
android:layout_alignBottom="id/txt" 
android:layout_toRightOf="id/txt" 
android:text="@string/..." 
android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

or

```
<TextView
android:id="+id/textView1" 
android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_alignBaseline="txt" 
android:layout_alignBottom="txt" 
android:layout_toRightOf="txt" 
android:text="@string/..." 
android:layout_marginLeft="3dp" 
android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```